# How to move a site to a new country with a new country top level domain?

Tags: domains, google-search-console, redirects, analytics, country-specific

We recently moved to Oz and we have bought a new domain name to launch over here. It is just a small run from home catering business, so searches are usually localized.

My original plan was to 301 redirect using htaccess and to use the webmaster tools change address function and then in a few months delete the old site.

I'm wondering whether this is needed, or should I just delete the old site and upload the slightly changed site to the new domain and request a google index. Anybody searching and coming across the old site would not be interested in visiting the new domain as we are in a new country now.

I will be changing content - i.e. where me mention our old town, this will be replaced with the new town, telephone number, address and email details.

Can someone advise what the best plan is in this case?

Answer (score 1):

**First thing** is how much traffic is at your old site? If old site has really good traffic and strong SEO then you should not take decision to remove old site and launch new quickly. You can redirect user to new site using 301 redirection rule.

**Second this** is that you can simply put alert message like visit our new site : www.yournewsite.com so when user will visit your old site they will definitely notice that you have launched new site.

**Third thing** is you will have to maintain proper SEO on new domain/new site. So if you decided to remove old site then make sure your new have strong SEO to maintain running traffic. Also if you are going to do something new then better you improve other site area like site design , content etc so people will feel really fresh look with new domain.

Comment: with the first option - does it even matter what the traffic was if the traffic I was getting in UK is now irrelevant in OZ? I.E they would previously search for bread maker London, now they will search for bread maker Sydney

Comment: You are right, then no need to worry for traffic. Then best way is you redirect user using 301 to new site , or just inform them by giving alert or something that you have new site.